# SVG Assets preferred in Xcode 13/14 over multiple PNG Images?

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode 12 introduced support for using Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG) image assets. It comes with a lot of benefits like smaller sizer, less management efforts, etc.

My question is: Does SVG also come with a sacrifice of compiling performance in the latest Xcode 13/14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My quick test validates one’s intuition, namely that compilation is faster (though, only slightly) if you prepare the 1×, 2×, and 3× scale rasterized images yourself beforehand. For my test with twenty, trivial 1k SVG (the standard `square.and.up.arrow` icon), that was 0.3 seconds slower building than it was with the same number of sets of pre-prepared PNGs.

So, it depends upon the number of vector graphics, and the size/complexity of those vector files. But in my current project with ~100 vector assets, the compilation time of the assets has never been the concern. But my assets are, admittedly, relatively simple. Your mileage may vary.

You probably are going to just have to benchmark it with your collection of images to decide whether the compilation time difference warrants the time investment to create all the rasterized assets. So look at your build report and you can see how much time is taken at this step in the build.

---

As an aside, you mention the smaller size. The assets in your project might be smaller, but the resulting app might not be any smaller.

I don’t use vector graphics for size reductions, but for the other reasons you enumerated. Plus, by preserving vector data, I get nice renditions in the accessibility vision scenarios (e.g., where tab buttons become oversized).